# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter'). I cannot find the where is error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my react code to filter the recommended movies:-
[filter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNpg2.png)

What is wrong with the code? What changes should be done?

react-redux:v7.2.6

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`moviesData` is expecting a type because .filter only works on arrays, type something like this:

```
type Movie = {
 is_premiere: boolean
}

const recommended movies = () => {
  const moviesData: Movie[] = useSelector((state) => state.moviesData);
 
// Rest of your code
}
```

Sorry for formatting, in typing from my phone

Comment: this code is not working . showing this annotation use in typescript.